# Minizinc: construct array of occurrences within another array

Tags: arrays, count, minizinc

I am able to generate an output with the array

`[3,2,2,3,3,3,1,4,2,4,5,2,3]`

I would like to create another array that counts the occurrence of each of the digits in the array, to then perform other constraints on them, e.g. forcing a min/max number of times they appear if not 0.

Doing something like this just yields errors, in this case `no function or predicate with this signature found: 'forall(array[int] of var int)'`.

```
set of int: DIGIT = 1..5;
set of int: COUNT = {0,2,3,4}
array[DIGIT] of var COUNT: occurrence;

constraint forall(i in DIGIT) (
  count(j in array_mentioned_above)(occurrence[i] = j)
);
```

I've also tried things like this with swapping around the variable names and the count on the outside but still nothing.

```
array[DIGIT] of var COUNT: occurrence = forall(i in DIGIT) (
  count(j in array_mentioned_above)(occurrence[i] = j)
);
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is a model showing two different ways of counting the number of occurrences of the values in an array (here `x`). The first approach uses the `count` constraint (as in your model), but the recommended approach is the second one: using the global constraint `global_cardinality`; this constraint is often optimized by the FlatZinc solvers.

MiniZinc has a lot of different global constraint for counting stuff, see more in the MinZinc Handbook: https://www.minizinc.org/doc-2.5.5/en/lib-globals.html#counting-constraints

```
include "globals.mzn";

int:n = 13;
array[1..n] of int: x = [3,2,2,3,3,3,1,4,2,4,5,2,3];

set of int: DIGIT = {x[i] | i in 1..n};
set of int: COUNT = 0..n;
array[DIGIT] of var COUNT: occ;
array[DIGIT] of var COUNT: gcc;

% using count
constraint
   forall(i in DIGIT) (
        occ[i] = count(x,i)
   )
;

% Using global_cardinality
constraint
   global_cardinality(x,DIGIT,gcc)
;


output [
  "DIGIT: \(DIGIT)\n",
  "occ: \(occ)\n",
  "gcc: \(gcc)"
]
```

The output is:

```
DIGIT: 1..5
occ: [1, 4, 5, 2, 1]
gcc: [1, 4, 5, 2, 1]
----------
==========
```